# Using SSMS To Connect to Database Created using MySQL Command Line Client

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface, ssms, localdb

I made a database using the MySql Command Line Client (8.0). I am `root@localhost`. This is my database (toys):

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
| toys               |
+--------------------+
```

I opened SSMS and want to query my database toys via this studio. I connected to `mssqllocaldb` by default.

[image: SSMS]

But I cannot see where my toys DB resides. It is clear to me that it isn't residing under `mssqllocaldb` since I did not even require a password to access this location, while the command-line asks me for my password.

My question is, why isn't `toys` under `mssqllocaldb` and how can I connect to `toys` via SSMS?

Thanks

Comment: Even if you did all that https://superuser.com/questions/163610/anyway-to-use-ssms-to-connect-to-mysql  . it is  a huge step. so why not use Mysql workbench?

Comment: @nbk What will using MySQL Workbench allow me to do? My goal is to have C# talk to my database using EntityFramework. It seems like anything done with MySQL Command Line can only stay local? Hence, it might be better to simply reject the idea of connecting SSMS to my local command line instance and instead connect to and play around with MSSQLLocalDB?

Comment: SSMS is designed for ms sql server and not for mysql. It cannot directly connect to a mysql server. If you want to use a GUI tool to manage mysql, you need to choose something else, like mysql workbench.

Comment: Btw, the GUI tool has nothing to do with how you connect to your database from code. Also, pls not that ms sql server and mysql are two different products, this is why you cannot see your toys database in ms sql server.

Comment: I use ssms for sql servers and workbench for mysql, they do the same for each. As you can see in my link, you have to connect ssms via odbc to connect to mysql. As always read the mysql website how to connect to mysql database https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Comment: @Shadow So using Workbench is just a GUI for the Command Line and won't help me have my code speak to MySQL. Is that correct? In that case I guess it's best for me to simply deal with a Ms SQL Server (replicate my Toys database from MySQL in MS SQL Server)

Comment: SSMS is also just a GUI, nothing more.